# When I generate a migration in ruby on rails it creates a file with empty methods, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I simply wish to rename a column in my DB. Ofcourse I just drop the DB and make changes then migrate but I want to do it a more practical way.

How can I create a migration that creates a change method with correct info inside so all I have to do is run rake db:migrate?

Command I'm running:

```
rails generate migration rename_column :profiles, :racial_background, :ethnicity
```

Empty methods:

```
class RenameColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only adding and removing columns can be implied by using the generator.

> If the migration name is of the form “AddXXXToYYY” or “RemoveXXXFromYYY” and is followed by a list of column names and types then a migration containing the appropriate add_column and remove_column statements will be created.

[Source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration)

Comment: So to rename I would have to create the migration then manually enter the info into the file?

Comment: @GregoryHouse yes. I think you could use the new `def change ... end` method only though for renaming columns, it should be able to guess the `down` equivalent itself.